# Requiring a file from another WordPress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I don't appear to be able to require a PHP file that is part of another plugin.

Let's say we're trying to include **/wp-content/plugins/plugin-from/src/classes/admin-class.php**

The require_once statements that we've tried so far provide a "*no such file or directory*" error, though declaring a class with the same name as the one included in admin-class.php returns a *cannot redeclare class*" error.

None of the following methods have produced results:

```
require_once 'admin-class.php';
require_once '../../plugin-from/src/classes/admin-class.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/../../plugin-from/src/classes/admin-class.php';
```

Declaring a global object reference and calling it also returned NULL from var_dump

Once this is working the plan is to instantiate an object of the class in admin-class.php and pass a variable to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

`require_once( ABSPATH . '/wp-content/plugins/plugin-from/src/classes/admin-class.php');`